Pause after Alert
I've got the following code that is supposed to prompt the user that a question has been submitted, and then refresh the page:
protected void ButtonSubmitQuestionClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    -- A whole bunch of code that does stuff --

    //close window
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Your question has been submitted!');window.close();", true);
    Response.Redirect("~/QA_QuestionIntake.aspx");
}

The problem is, the popup never appears, presumably because the page refreshes immediately.  How can I make the code pause on the alert until the user presses a button?

Move the redirect logic to the JS block. Can not mix the server side codes with client side js and handle the order of execution.
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "alertAndRedirect", "alert('Your question has been submitted!');window.location = '~/QA_QuestionIntake.aspx';", true);

